# Codeigniter Getting std object Value from arrray

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session

I have stored an array in the session variable in a controller. I want to access the element of that array in another controller method, is it possible?

Here $result is returning an array and I have assigned array to the codeigniter session.

```
$result = $this->insert->verify_user($val);
                    $this->session->set_userdata($result);
                    return true;
```

I am getting the Custom Session Data like this

```
$this->session->userdata('id');
```

but it shows nothing to me,

when I do `var_dump ($this->session->all_userdata());`

it shows me:

```
array
  'session_id' => string '585429364de0b70ee3887dfe44c4c8ce' (length=32)
  'ip_address' => string '127.0.0.1' (length=9)
  'user_agent' => string 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0' (length=72)
  'last_activity' => int 1396524445
  'user_data' => string '' (length=0)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[17]
      public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'username' => string 'admin' (length=5)
      public 'password' => string 'admin' (length=5)
  'username' => string 'admin' (length=5)
  'password' => string 'admin' (length=5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a codeignitor user, but it seems you need to set the data within an associative array so you know what key to lookup:

```
    $result = $this->insert->verify_user($val);
    $this->session->set_userdata(array('somekey'=>$result));
    return true;

    $this->session->userdata('somekey')->id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `session` value in a variable and the access it by array index

```
$data =  $this->session->all_userdata();
echo $data[0]->id;
```